# How is English stereotyped by non-native speakers?

Tags: pronunciation

It's possible to parody other languages by how they sound. Even if you don't know any words of that language you can make pretend speech which others will recognise as being that language.

eg German is full of *sch*, *acht*, *vie* (wie), *unt*

Italian is full of *iano*, *gnore*, *ucci*

(I'm sorry I don't know how to write these phonetically, and I certainly don't mean to offend anyone).

What I'd like to know is how would people from other countries parody English? What are the determining sounds that distinguish English from other languages? How would you mock English speakers in this way?

(Light hearted mocking of course. I'm not trying to start an international incident here.)

Comment: I suggest you to take a look into [phonotactics of the English language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Phonotactics). But unfortunately, this question, as it stands, is not constructive. I'm closing it, but if you have any other question on the subject (take a look at the [FAQ](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/344/linguistics-community-faq)), feel free to post another one.

Comment: Lots of th, the distinctive English r sound, diphthongs and schwas are the first things that spring to my mind there. ;)

Comment: Go to You-Tube and enter "fake English."  You'll find multiple links to videos of foreigners pretending to speak English.  The "er" sound figures prominently.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo: Aww but I really like this question!

Comment: I think this could be a good question if phrased better. Perhaps something like: 'what features of English do speakers of other languages focus on when attempting to imitate/parody English?'. The answer would probably depend on the 'other language' but I think there's potential for interesting answers.

Comment: Similar question on Chinese.SE: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6325/do-the-chinese-have-a-potentially-politically-incorrect-way-of-imitating-engli